# Pushing React component to javascript Array does not store actual return values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to push a React component into a javascript array. I am expecting the values in that array to be what the React component returns. Instead of that I get an array containing objects of like this: `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)...`.

Here is my code: loads books from an API when button is clicked and appends then to list of books already displayed (basically infinite scrolling):

**Books**:

```
function Books({ page }) {
  const fetcher = url => api.get(url).then(response => response.data);
  const { data: books } = useSWR(
    `/books?page=${page}`,
    fetcher
  );

  return books ? (
    <>
      {books.map(book => (
        <Book key={book.id} book={book} />
      ))}
    </>
  ) : null;
}
```

**IndexPage**:

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pages: 1 };
  }

  load = () => {
    this.setState({ pages: this.state.pages + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    const books = [];
    for (let page = 1; page <= this.state.pages; page++)
      books.push(<Books page={page} key={page} />);    

    console.log(books) // logs `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)...` instead of `[null]`.

    return (
      <>
        {books.length ? (
          books
        ) : (

          // This never executes because `books.length` is never zero
          <li>No books yet.</li>
        )}

        <button onClick={this.load}>Load More Books</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**My goal is to find a way to display `<li>No books yet.</li>` in the code below but I cannot find a way to do it dealing with the values I find in the array.** Right now, if there are no objects I just see a blank page.

How can I make sure that the React component actual return values are stored in my array instead of these "symbol" objects?

Comment: Those are as actual objects as you're going to get – only when React.js renders the element objects you get HTML. What do you actually want to do here?

Comment: Figure out a way to display `<li>No books yet.</li>` when the books array is empty... Nothing more, nothing less...

Comment: What fails in your code? Looks fine to me

Comment: I updated question. Basically I cannot figure out a way to display message when books array is empty. Right now I just see a blank page.

Comment: Well, you are always pushing a `<Books />` element into the array so long as `this.state.pages` >= 1.

Comment: After all, you can't know whether or not there are books before you've fetched them. Perhaps you should move the fetch/fetch more logic into the `IndexPage` component?

Comment: I'm confused.  Your state starts out with `page:1`, your forloop sets `books` array by `for (let page = 1; page <= this.state.pages; page++)`, so, there will always *be* books, because `1 <= 1` is TRUE, and it will pass one iteration.  Yet you're trying to display "No books yet" when it's zero, which is always false.

Comment: True, but when I call Books and there aren't any actual books in my database I am kind of expecting to get back and empty array (or something with 1 null element in it)

Comment: Then change your logic to start out with pages: 0, so you'll have zero pages, which, will then display it correctly.

Comment: But I do want to start out with books for when there are some...

Comment: Hi, fredperk: Did you finally figure out lifecycles of API-based, react projects?  Let me know if my answer helped at all, at least in explaining what's going on.  Seems like someone liked my answer, and someone didn't!  But I got no explanation, so I have no idea why.

Comment: I worked around it by using a global variable to indicate whether there are more definitions available to be loaded. I might post an answer in the future if I have time

Comment: @fredperk: [Global variables are bad.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/485020/2430549)  Please don't post that answer.  I recommend understanding the documentation before attempting an answer, for instance, like the documentation linked in my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You always want to set your default state in the constructor in ReactJS.  Take a look at the official documentation...

> Add a class constructor that assigns the initial this.state:
>
> ```
>  constructor(props) {
>    super(props);
>    this.state = {date: new Date()};
>  }
> ```

Source: [**ReactJS.org: State and Lifecycle / Adding Local State to a Class**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

If you're using an API, you can update the state once the `fetch()` or `ajax()` requests finally resolve, and fill the state with useful data.  Since you want to show "no books yet" when there's nothing loaded yet, indicate this in the state; remove `pages:1` (as there are no pages) and set `pages:0`...

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { pages: 0 };
}
```

Then your statement should work and show correctly, as the condition for showing it is now true: `books.length ?`.  Of course, you may want to get even more fancy, and indicate the difference between *loading* and *nothing found.*  For instance...

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { pages: 0, loaded: false };
}
```

And in your `render()` call...

```
render() {
    if(!this.state.loaded) {
        return (<span> loading api </span>);
    }
    return (
        {books.length ? (
              books
            ) : (
    
              // This never executes because `books.length` is never zero
              <li>No books yet.</li>
            )}
    )
}
```

Then later in your code, once your API has done its loading...

```
this.setState({pages: somepagenumber, loaded: true});
```